# hide input and only display output (PYTHON) as well as another small issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, dns, ip-address

I am creating an nslookup utility tool in python using socket.

Code:

```
import socket


while True:
    try:
        server = input()
        ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(server)
        print(server, ip_addr, '\n')
    except socket.gaierror:
        print(server, 'unable to find ip')
        break
```

---

returns:

google.com
google.com 172.217.8.14

yahoo.com
yahoo.com 98.138.219.231

domain.domain.domain
domain.domain.domain unable to find ip

stackoverflow.com

---

So I want to hide the input so that only the following is displayed:

google.com 172.217.8.14

yahoo.com 98.138.219.231

domain.domain.domain unable to find ip

---

I also noticed that  the last entry never gets ran through the script and I have to manually hit enter for "stackoverflow.com" to lookup the IP. Is there anyway around that?

I appreciate any help in advance!
Thanks!

Comment: I should note that it looks like the input and output are on one line but I messed up on the formatting. the first address is above the output and ip.

Comment: From the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248142/what-can-i-use-to-go-one-line-break-back-in-a-terminal-in-python): Use `\033[1A` . I was not able to get rid of a space character for some reason I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just don’t print the server name, this will work:

```py
import socket


while True:
    try:
        server = input()
        ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(server)
        print(ip_addr, '\n')
    except socket.gaierror:
        print('unable to find ip')
        break
```

Also you have to hit enter, the interpreter can’t understand when you are done writing

Comment: This is what I had initially and while this works, I am trying to get the output "server,  ip_addr" to display on one line!

Comment: @avgnetmin You could could use this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q76eeh4l2p46o54/Code.py?dl=0

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use getpass instead of input if this is want you want.

e.g

```
import getpass.getpass

server = getpass()
```

Comment: but I would prefer to use @ArcticFox's answer
edit: but only if you not want to hide the output itself but don't want to see the domain 2 times